# Problem with tabulary when used inside user macro

Tags: environments, tabulary

I have having problems with tabulary inside a user macro.  The purpose of the macro is to decide whether to use a longtable or tabulary, depending on the number of rows.  Below is a MWE (or a MNWE, given that it demonstrates the problem):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{longtable} 
\usepackage{tabulary}

% Macro to decide on type of table to use depending on number of rows.
\newcommand{\tableintro}[2]{\ifnum #1 > 10
  \begin{longtable}{#1}
\else
  \begin{table}[h!]
  \tabulary{\columnwidth}{#1}
\fi}

\newcommand{\tableend}[1]{\ifnum #1 > 10
  \end{longtable}
\else
  \endtabulary
  \end{table}
\fi}

\begin{document}

Declare a short table with two rows and three columns:

\tableintro{2}{r r r}
10 & 5 & 8.5 \\
10 & 5 & 8.5
\tableend{2}

\end{document}
```

If I change the macro from tabulary to tabular (and remove the \columnwidth) it works.  If I type the same tabulary table directly without the macros, it works.    However, for some reason it fails when using tabulary inside the macro.  I get this error:

```
! File ended while scanning use of \TY@get@body.
```

but I can't see why.

Comment: as documented you would need to use `\tabulary` and `\endtabulary` forms as `tabulary` needs to grab the entire environment  so looks for `\end{tabulary}` in the source document. Also, unrelated, don't put `longtable` in a center environment,

Comment: Thanks David.  I tried using `\tabulary` and `\endtabulary`, but the error message is the same.  Also, I removed the center - thanks for the tip :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

In common with most environments that grab their body as an argument, you need to use the command form when nesting.  Also the syntax ought to be an environment, and you need to account for tabulary needing LCR columns:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{longtable} 
\usepackage{tabulary}

% Macro to decide on type of table to use depending on number of rows.
\newenvironment{tableintro}[1]{%
\ifnum #1 > 10
\newcolumntype{R}{r}%
\let\endtableintro\endlongtable
\expandafter\longtable
\else
  \def\endtableintro{\endtabulary\endtable}%
  \def\tmp{\table[htp!]\tabulary{\columnwidth}}%
  \expandafter\tmp
\fi}%
{}


\begin{document}

Declare a short table with two rows and three columns:

\begin{tableintro}{2}{R R R}
10 & 5 & 8.5 \\
10 & 5 & 8.5
\end{tableintro}

\begin{tableintro}{20}{R R R}
10 & 5 & 8.5 \\
10 & 5 & 8.5
\end{tableintro}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks David, that worked nicely.  I learned a few new things from your code and was able to add in the other bits and pieces I needed.  Cheers!